# standalone git server for a team

Tags: self-hosted, git

I usually use github repositories or repositories local to any organization that employs me. Now I should install a local standalone repository with git for a team. I could get it to work with gitweb + standalone git server but my team leader said that there could be a problem because it only allowed "one user". But I could set up 2 different ssh keys and commit from 2 different machines as 2 different users.

What software would you suggest for this constellation?

Comment: Note that this site is not about "is this software fitting my needs" – but about "what software meets these requirements". So I've interpreted your question as specifying the requirements, and answered it accordingly. Hope it fits!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **[Gogs](https://gogs.io/)** or its fork **[Gitea](https://gitea.io/)**. Both are free and open source, allow you multiple users, are easy to set up, and work reliably.

I'm using *Gitea* for a while as it has a more flexible team driving the development, and am pretty much satisfied with it. It offers an experience comparable with *Github,* so you have:

- multiple users, each with multiple repositories
- for each repo, an issue tracker and a wiki

Being cross-platform, you should find your suitable binary easily. They also have a demo set up, if you want to take a look first.